# Understand TimeSeriesSplit in scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

From the [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) at the scikit-learn homepage I understand the workflow using TimeSeriesSplit would look something like this in pseudocode:

```
large_train, large_test = split_whole_dataset(df)
for epoch in epochs:
   for train, validate in tscv.split(large_train):
      params = standardize(train)
      standarize(validate, using=params)
evaluate_model_using_data(large_test) #<--- How to standardize this data????
```

What confuses me here are two things:
First I would train the model over the same data that I test it on for each epoch? So when I do the second epoch I will have trained the model on all the validation data?

Second thing, what values do I use to standardize the hold out test data (large_test), since I do repetedly standardization within the inner loop I dont know which parameters to use when standardizing the test data?